# Show Alert to user for result of API call with onItemSaved event

Tags: events, sheer-ui

I have a class that uses the `onItemSaved` method to make a call to an external API when a particular type of item is updated and saved.

I need to display a message to the user about the success/failure of that API call.

I can set a message to return based on the response from the call, but it is not getting displayed.

```
namespace Macmillan.Feature.Services.Handlers
{
    public class YextAPI
    {
        // TODO: Move these to config file and handle via transforms
        private static readonly string BaseUrl = {{URL}};

        private static readonly string Account = {{ACCOUNT}};

        private static readonly string Type = {{TYPE OF ENTITY}};

        private static readonly string ApiKey = {{API KEY}};

        private static readonly string Version = {{VERSION}};

        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

        public void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (!(Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) is Item item) || !"master".Equals(item.Database?.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!item.TemplateID.Equals(new ID("{8023690C-01C2-4C03-ACED-70AA3B862CE1}")))
            {
                return false;
            }

            string entityId = item.Fields["Entity ID"].Value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityId))
            {
                return false;
            }

            this.HandleRequest(item);

        }

        private static string GetServiceDetails(Item item)
        {
            // ...get all the item details and return a json object
        }

        // Handle the API request
        private async Task<string> HandleRequest(Item item)
        {
            string entityId = item.Fields["Entity ID"].Value;

            string content = GetServiceDetails(item);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await this.UpdateEntity(content, entityId);

            string message = await this.GetResultMessage(response);

            SheerResponse.Alert(message); // THIS METHOD GETS SKIPPED

            return response.ReasonPhrase;
        }
  
        // Get the message to display depending on the result
        private async Task<string> GetResultMessage(HttpResponseMessage response)
        {
            HttpStatusCode responseMessage = response.StatusCode;

            string message = string.Empty;

            if (responseMessage.Equals(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                message = "Yext Entity updated successfully!";
            }

            if (!responseMessage.Equals(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(responseString);

                message = "Sorry, there was an error updating the Yext entity, please try again.";
            }

            return message;
        }

        // Make the API call
        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateEntity(string content, string entityID)
        {
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

            var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);

            byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            string endpointUrl = $"{BaseUrl}/{Account}/{Type}/{entityID}?api_key={ApiKey}&v={Version}";

            HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PutAsync(endpointUrl, byteContent);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the `item:saved` event in my config file:

```
 <events>
      <event name="item:saved">
        <handler type="Macmillan.Feature.Services.Handlers.YextAPI, Macmillan.Feature.Services" method="OnItemSaved"/>
      </event>
    </events>
```

Where should I call `SheerResponse.Alert` so that it actually displays the message to the user?
I feel like the problem is to do with `onItemSaved` method continuing before the async method completes but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Try changing the type of `HandleRequest` result from `async Task<string>` to just `string` and returning `response.ReasonPhrase.Result`